# Php Простое регулярное выражение на поиск e-mail

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить рег. выражение.

Есть большой отладочный текст, из него необходимо достать **email** в рамке **"for"** и **";"** (внутри должен быть мейл, наверное достаточно проверки на существование @), выглядит текст примерно так:

```
Foreigners is still taking the decision on Your case. Thus today 04.10.2018, we 

sent a written request about the phase; for sacri.subba@yahoo.com;

text text text ... for today you; other e-mail test@mai.com;
```

Answer (score 5):

Для email достаточно простейшей проверки на формат ввода (наличие собачки и домена):

```
"^for [a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+;$"
```

Этой регуляркой найдёшь строчку, где содержится нужный тебе фрагмент `for user@example.com`. Далее можно сделать explode() этой строчки по пробелу и найти строку, соответствующую почте:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$"
```

Рабочее решение, полученное опытным путём:

```
$pattern = '/for [A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\;/ui'; 
preg_match($pattern, $text, $res);
if ($res) {
    $email = str_replace(';', '', explode(' ', $res[0])[1]);
}
```

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, что мейлов может быть несколько в тексте, а нужен только тот, который в FOR. Он один.

Comment: @mico внёс изменения в ответ

Comment: `preg_match("/^for [a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+;$/ui", $text, $res);` Возвращает ничего, т.е. $res = []

Comment: `$pattern = '/for [A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\;/ui';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $res);
if ($res) {
    $email = str_replace(';', '', explode(' ', $res[0])[1]);
}` Так получилось

Comment: @mico добавил в свой ответ рабочее решение

Comment: Если использовать захватывающую группу, можно обойтись одним `preg_match(_all)`

Answer (score 3):

В простом тексте все адреса электронной почты можно найти с помощью

```
preg_match_all('~\bfor\s+\K\S+@\S+\.\S+\b~u', $s, $matches)
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/7AX50H/1).

**Подробности**

- `\bfor` - целое слово `for`
- `\s+` - один и более пробельных символов
- `\K` - удаляем весь найденный до сих пор текст из совпадения
- `\S+@\S+` - один и более символов, отличных от пробельных, `@` и снова один и более символов, отличных от пробельных
- `\.` - точка
- `\S+` - один и более символов, отличных от пробельных
- `\b` - граница слова.

[PHP](https://ideone.com/o62vnM):

```
$s = <<<INPUT
Foreigners is still taking the decision on Your case. Thus today 04.10.2018, we 
sent a written request about the phase; for sacri.subba@yahoo.com;
text text text ... for today you; other e-mail test@mai.com
for  another###test@mai.com
INPUT;
if (preg_match_all('~\bfor\s+\K\S+@\S+\.\S+\b~u', $s, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => sacri.subba@yahoo.com
    [1] => another###test@mai.com
)
```